# Gmail SMTP through SSL is not working

Tags: smtp, gmail, phpmailer

How to get this work fine?

I am trying to send emails from my website using my Gmail account, I am using SMTP SSL, the username and password are ok and I can log into my account from the browser anytime. I googled the problem but nothing was quite helpful.

First I used to get a message says "SMTP Error: Could not authenticate"

I tried to use different ports like 25, 587, switch from SSL to TLS but that didn't solve the issue.

So my problem is how to properly "authenticate" (as what the message says) with Gmail?

Any help?

The below script returns an empty response!

```
<?php
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "SSL";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";  // specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = "username@gmail.com";  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "password"; // SMTP password

$mail->From = "username@gmail.com";
$mail->FromName = "username";
$mail->AddAddress("account@gmail.com", "account name");

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = "Here is the subject";
$mail->Body    = "This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>";
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients";

if(!$mail->Send())
{
   echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
   echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
```

?>

I tried to use different SMTP different than Gmail and worked just fine perfectly.

What could be the problem then?

Comment: Have you seen PHPMailer's [GMail example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps)?

Comment: Yup, it returns the same error.

Comment: Did you try turning on debugging as per the example?

Comment: Sure! I turned the debugger to 1 to get the complete error. I asked the server admin also:-) but he was kind of afraid cuz nothing seems wrong, so I decided to post a question over here...

Comment: Is it possible that PHP is not configured to use TLS/SSL? (I know very little about the specifics of PHP, but I remember there were a lot of settings.)

Comment: I did check the openssl from phpinfo(); and it was enabled on the server! that's what I know about the ssl, the server I am running the website on have only ssl valid certificate on the exchange mail server! will this prevent the authentication from been processed?

Comment: The PHP environment the script is running on needs it enabled.